# Dataset of bodybuilding exercises

Tags: data-request, sports

I am looking for a dataset of bodybuilding exercises that list which muscles are activated for each exercise in a machine readable way.

Answer (score 3):

Wger Workout Manager [provides](https://wger.de/en/software/api) a full REST API to all database objects under Affero GNU General Public License (AGPL) Version 3+. You can use  API or download [datasets](https://github.com/wger-project/wger/tree/master/wger/exercises/fixtures) from GitHub.

Additionally:

- Many bodybuilding sites are well-scrapable, see e. g. [this example](https://www.reddit.com/r/datasets/comments/2bu31y/873_different_weight_lifting_and_strength/cj9do25/) for
  bodybuilding.com;
- Many Android apps contain all their information in local SQLite databases (e. g. [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=softin.my.fast.fitness));