# Yoga, Gym, Fitness API

Tags: api, uses-of-open-data, medical

I have been searching for an API to get the **Yoga, Gymnastic** exercises details and curriculum with appropriate steps and measures. I am planning to use these details for my upcoming project.

As to my search, I have not found any links and references that fulfills my requirements.

Google and other companies are providing **Fitness API**, but they are confined to their application and usage. As for general purpose, they are not helping out to solve my current problem.

Also please provide *links and references* from where I can get complete details about Yoga and Gymnasium as well.

Comment: Related question: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/11488/16193